# How to display contents of a .phtml template file in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout

I've been trying to add some php logic to view the things I want. I found out that the proper way to do this using a block template in a .phtml file in the /view/frontend/templates folder of the module.

**What I've tried**

In my module's layout(checkout_index_index.xml) file added this:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
      <block class="DeliveryMatch\Shipping\Block\DmCarrier" name="dm-shipping" template="DeliveryMatch_Shipping::checkout/shipping/carrier_custom.phtml" before="shippingAdditional" cacheable="false" />
</referenceContainer>
```

To display the contents of the .phtml before shippingAdditional

> app/code/DeliveryMatch/Shipping/Block/DmCarrier.php

```
<?php
namespace DeliveryMatch\Shipping\Block\DmCarrier;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class DmCarrier extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->setData('contacts',array());
    }


}
```

And the .phtml file in

> view/frontend/templates/checkout/shipping/carrier_custom.phtml

```
<h1><?php echo 'Test'; ?></h1>
```

But this is not displayed in the checkout.

**What I need**

Display the contents of

> templates/checkout/shipping/carrier_custom.phtml

Inside the shippingAdditional field

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Then you can use it**

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("DeliveryMatch\Shipping\Block\DmCarrier\DmCarrier")->setTemplate("DeliveryMatch_Shipping::checkout/shipping/carrier_custom.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Comment: In what file can I use this? And where to setup the file so it's used by the checkout?

Answer (score -1):

You can insert your block into other template file '.phtml' of checkout.

```
<div style="" class="col-md-12 with-padleft">
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()
               ->createBlock("DeliveryMatch\Shipping\Block\DmCarrier\DmCarrier")
               ->toHtml(); 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: In what file is this? Can you include the file path?

Comment: For example. if you want to add your block in 'module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml' you need to copy this file into your module ''DeliveryMatch' that look like 'DeliveryMatch/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml'